# parsing a string from a textfield into a double

Tags: java, parsing, double, gettext

I'm trying to parse a string from a text field into a double:

`Double.parseDouble(variable.getText())`

Yet the program throws the following exception:

`error: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException at gpacalculator.xGPA.calGPAbtnActionPerformed(xGPA.java:341)`

Here are my declarations:

```
private void calGPAbtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
  String q1,q2,q3,q4,q5,q6,q7,q8,w1,w2,w3,w4,w5,w6,w7,w8;
    q1 = course1.getText();
    q2 = course2.getText();
    q3 = course3.getText();
    q4 = course4.getText();
    q5 = course5.getText();
    q6 = course6.getText();
    q7 = course13.getText();
    q8 = course15.getText();
    w1 = course7.getText();
    w2 = course8.getText();
    w3 = course9.getText();
    w4 = course10.getText();
    w5 = course11.getText();
    w6 = course12.getText();
    w7 = course14.getText();
    w8 = course16.getText();

    gpaCal.setUnits1(Double.parseDouble(q1));
    gpaCal.setUnits2(q2);
    gpaCal.setUnits3(q3);
    gpaCal.setUnits4(q4);
    gpaCal.setUnits5(q5);
    gpaCal.setUnits6(q6);
    gpaCal.setUnits7(q7);
    gpaCal.setUnits8(q8);
    gpaCal.setGrade1(w1);
    gpaCal.setGrade2(w2);
    gpaCal.setGrade3(w3);
    gpaCal.setGrade4(w4);
    gpaCal.setGrade5(w5);
    gpaCal.setGrade6(w6);
    gpaCal.setGrade7(w7);
    gpaCal.setGrade8(w8);
}
```

Note: I only tried to parse the first one to display the idea of the code.

Comment: a NullPointerException is thrown when an application attempts to use null in a case where an object is required. Set a breakpoint at that line and check every single object on that line to see whether they are null or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet your NPE is propagated up the call stack, that's why it's caught at `xGPA.java:341`.

```
final String variableText = (variable != null) ? variable.getText() : null;
final Double result = (variableText != null) ? Double.parseDouble(variableText) : 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

From the `Double#parseDouble(String)` JavaDoc: *Throws NullPointerException if the string is null*

You need to check for null (and perhaps on the variable as well if that can be null) before parsing, so something like this:

```
if(variable != null && variable.getText() != null) {
    Double.parseDouble(variable.getText()
}
```

Comment: `variable` may be null too

Comment: Good point, I'll add it.

Comment: getText() throws NPE if the document is empty

Comment: OK, so that's probably the reason you're getting there. You can also add an else clause that passes 0.0 if you need a double value.

Comment: i posted some of the code above. i hope that helps

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure if this adds much to the situation, if line 341 is actually the line you're parsing the double in, it's probably the solution I proposed, otherwise you're going to have to show us the kind of objects the courses are. Have you tried checking the values of q1...q8 etc. with debug prints or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Check if string is null first. i.e. If no text has been entered in your textfield, this will return an error.

Comment: when running the program, I input "3" in the first textfield. Is it still null there?

Comment: No. All textfields with text in them will return the required String.